# Loop through Hive or SQL Rows by assigning values in descending order

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

For a hive or sql table with 5 rows, how do i split a value = 12, and assign it to rows in a descending order. For example, as mentioned in the following table, where the sum of column (total) is 12 and the values are assigned in descending order.

```
column_1    column_2    total
   a           b          3
   c           d          3
   e           f          2
   g           h          2
   i           j          2
```

Comment: Why all those different dbms tags? Remove the ones not involved.

Comment: What do you mean "assign to rows in descending order"?  I'm quite unclear on what you are trying to do.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I have to assign values in decremental order from the top row to bottom row, so that i would get a total sum of 12. As of you can see from my example table, the top two rows got values of 3,3 and then the bottom rows got 2,2,2. Therefore, the total sum came up to 12. Let's suppose if want a total sum of 11 only, then the values should be 3,2,2,2,2 assigned to rows from top to bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parametrize this query using hivevar variables. I tested it with few different values of total=12, 11, 16, it seems to work correctly. Please optimize and debug it by yourself. I just provided the idea:

```
with vars as(--calculate min_value, max_value and how many rows with max_value it should be (max_rows)
select
       ceil(total/num_rows)                 as max_value, 
       floor(total/num_rows)                as min_value,
       total-floor(total/num_rows)*num_rows as max_rows
from
(select 5 num_rows, 12 total)s --your variables, parametrize using hivevar variables
),

your_table as (--use your table instead of this
select stack(5,
   'a', 'b',
   'c', 'd',
   'e', 'f',
   'g', 'h',
   'i', 'j'
) as (column_1,column_2)
)-- this is your_table, suppose column_1 determines the order of rows

select column_1,column_2, case when rn<=max_rows then max_value else min_value end as total
       --, rn, min_value, max_value, max_rows --debug values
from
(
select t.*, row_number() over(order by column_1) rn,  
       v.min_value, 
       v.max_value, 
       v.max_rows
 from your_table t
      cross join vars v
)s;
```

Result:

```
column_1    column_2    total   
a   b   3   
c   d   3   
e   f   2   
g   h   2   
i   j   2
```

For total=11 it returns:

```
column_1    column_2    total   
a   b   3   
c   d   2   
e   f   2   
g   h   2   
i   j   2
```

For total=16 it returns:

```
column_1    column_2    total   
a   b   4   
c   d   3   
e   f   3   
g   h   3   
i   j   3
```

Of course, it can still be some bug there, needs to be carefully tested before used as a component of nuclear reactor control. Not tested with different number of rows in initial table. But it definitely works for initial conditions in your question.

Also it is possible to optimize by calculating the number of rows as `count(*) over() as num_rows` in the query from your table and parametrize only one parameter: total (it is 12 in your example). The logic of calculating max_value, min_value and max_rows can be moved to the same query from your_table, without cross join, you can do the same without vars subquery.

Comment: Thanks, i made some tweaking to your code, it helped me a lot!!